# Interpolate data with columns that start or end with NA values in R

Tags: r, interpolation, na

I'm interpolating data, but columns with rows that start or end with NA values will not interpolate. 
The only solution I've found is to delete those NA rows at the start or end of the column, but this is not ideal because I want to keep those rows.

Example of dataframe (df) inputted:

```
year    value
2000    NA
2001    NA
2002    9
2003    7
2004    NA
2005    6
2006    NA
2007    4
2008    NA
```

Code snippet:

```
install.packages("zoo")
library(zoo) 

newValue <- na.approx(df$value)
df$Value <- newValue
```

The desired output:

```
year    value
2000    NA
2001    NA
2002    9
2003    7
2004    6.5
2005    6
2006    5
2007    4
2008    NA
```

How do you interpolate the data when the first or last row has an NA value, while keeping those rows?

Comment: Use `na.approx(df$value, na.rm = FALSE)`

Comment: This works--many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Solution via @akrun

```
newValue <- na.approx(df$value, na.rm = FALSE) 
df$Value <- newValue
```